# Running Mezzanine on App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, blogs

I am looking for a blog solution to run inside a Django project deployed on the Google App Engine.  After a bit of review I decided to try out Mezzanine v0.11.3.  I've overcome the hurdle of getting it in project using the advice of others deploying on App Engine at this link:  http://groups.google.com/group/mezzanine-users/browse_thread/thread/c8b13c41a3168c94.

Mezzanine is now showing up in the Admin, but clicking on Blog posts leads to a multi-table inheritance failure.  I believe that this is due to multi-site support functionality in Mezzanine via use of the Django sites framework.

Has anyone overcome this issue?  I'm going to try to use django-dbindexer but I'm not confident it will work.

*Update:  as far as I can tell, the folks at AllButtonsPressed don't have any magic solutions to work around ManyToManyField issues yet, so I think that option is dead.

If no one knows a work around, do any of you know of a good blog solution I can run inside a Django project on the App Engine?

*Update: found this post [Integrating Blogger into a Google App Engine App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053342/integrating-blogger-into-a-google-app-engine-app).  Will investigate if this solves the problem.

*Current Status:
I have not been able to solve this problem and I don't think it is currently solvable.  Thought I would share what I found through my investigations though; maybe someone out there can carry on and come up with a solution.

Options tried:

Bloog

- I looked this over but it is a Python
  solution, not a Django solution and I
  didn't want to do the work to turn it
  into one

Byteflow ( https://bitbucket.org/piranha/byteflow/wiki/Home ) notes:

- designed to be standalone, will need a
  lot of edits to settings.py,
  inclusion of 12 additional apps and
  overrides on account settings plus
  hand tuning at every upgrade.

AppEngineBlog ( http://code.google.com/p/appengineblogsoftware/ ) notes:

- written in appengine specific code,
  not maintained, no example sites
  available to see how it looks

Coltrane ( http://code.google.com/p/coltrane-blog/source/browse/ ):

- simple blog constructed from standard
  Django functionality no development
  or support, basically need to use
  this code as a way to develop your
  own blog and go from there

Flother ( https://github.com/flother/flother ):

- found via Coltrane comments, probably
  embeddable without too much trouble,
  requires 8 additional apps,the photos
  and places components have
  ManyToManyFields that would have to
  be re-written or these components
  disabled

Blogger API ( http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/ ):

- use Blogger at whatever location you
  wish to gain fully functional
  blogging capabilities, then use
  Blogger API to deliver content to any
  other site you wish to display it

Flother came close to what I need but there is still a fair bit of uncertainty and effort there.  I'm proceeding with the Blogger option as the only viable choice for me at this time.

Comment: [Mezzanine] - It seems things are moving the right way. Would you like to have a look at this thread and share your thoughts? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mezzanine-users/Z_8siaHWZuA/yHEITsjYsnEJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can see, there is no way to get Mezzanine running on GAE other than wading into the code and ripping out anything relating to a ManyToManyField (Sites support, Photos and ... something else.  Can't remember what).

The only thing I could find out there that has the potential to be added to an existing project, uses only portable Django code (app engine specific) and runs on App Engine is http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/allbuttonspressed .  I haven't actually tried to integrate it yet because I'm going to see if the Blogger solution works.

Comment: Another problem with Mezzanine on App Engine seems to be its reliance on the future library, which has C code that will not run on app engine. Please let me know if this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [bloog](http://github.com/Arachnid/bloog) for two of my blogs without any serious troubles so far - there are few little quirks that make it mildly unpleasant sometimes but nothing that's been a deal breaker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll check Bloog out today.

Comment: I decided not to got this route since it is only Python - not Django - based.  Unless I missed something ...

Answer (score 0):

I use the Blogger solution and it works fine, especially if you're only one person and you run the whole site.

The problem comes when you want to others to help you out.  Now every css and design decision needs to be sent to a programmer who hacks away at django templates.  A CMS with a real WYSIWYG editor would allow you to ship off that work to marketing/design people and let you focus on the fun stuff.

I came across a [decent review of the various blogging engines](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/) for Django, however, it's unclear how well they each integrate with GAE.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed Mezzanine/Cartridge in GAE succesfully but I have not documented it yet in github or something like that. It works using python 2.7 of course and django 1.5. Additionally it works with Google Cloud SQL, and the local file system GAE provides. It additionally works with google gmail facilities. For thumbnailing I am using local GAE functionality.
It requires several additional libraries like boto, but it works well.
See a short demo in midevocional365.appspot.com/